# Should I Un-Asyncify Randomly Working Code?

Tags: c#, http-post, task-parallel-library, async-await, filestream

I have some aync code that sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't. With this code, the file is always created, but sometimes it is empty (I always send a file that has content):

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/inventory/sendxml/{userId}/{pwd}/{filename}")]
public async void SendInventoryXML(String userId, String pwd, String fileName)
{
    Task task = Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        var stream = t.Result;
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(String.Format(@"C:\HDP\{0}.xml", fileName), (int)stream.Length))
        {
            byte[] bytesInStream = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(bytesInStream, 0, (int)bytesInStream.Length);
            fileStream.Write(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);
        }
    });
}
```

So, should I un-Asyncify this randomly working code and, if so, how (what would accomplish the same thing without the vagaries of unsyncness (assuming that's the problem causing this random behavior))?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using the await keyword? My guess is that when the SendInventoryXML method finishes the Request object is deallocated. And it will finish right after you called the ReadStreamAsync() method (without waiting for it to finish). The await keyword will force it to wait for the result.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/inventory/sendxml/{userId}/{pwd}/{filename}")]
public async void SendInventoryXML(String userId, String pwd, String fileName)
{
    var stream = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(String.Format(@"C:\HDP\{0}.xml", fileName), (int)stream.Length))
    {
        byte[] bytesInStream = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(bytesInStream, 0, (int)bytesInStream.Length);
        fileStream.Write(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your randomly working code is random because you're return a void and there is no way for the async framework to get a callback when it is finished. For an `async` method that returns `void`, change it to return a `Task` instead.

Also, why are you creating a `Task` inside your method? use `await`. You're basically returning and your processs may or may not complete before it's deallocated by the framework.

```
var stream = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

    using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(String.Format(@"C:\HDP\{0}.xml", fileName), (int)stream.Length))
    {
        byte[] bytesInStream = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(bytesInStream, 0, (int)bytesInStream.Length);
        fileStream.Write(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);
    }
```

Comment: Somebody else told me that a couple of days ago, but changing it to Task caused it not to work at all - the code was never reached when I did that.

Comment: Async will work with return type or no return type. Entirely up to developer if they want a return type. Do you have a callback handler? I would assume the cases of empty file are throwing an Exception and with no call back handler you are unaware.

Comment: returning `void`, you will not know if your code is crashing. A `Task` will trap the exception.

Comment: You can also wrap your code in a try/catch and trace log the exception.